# php form not posting email and textarea data

Tags: php, mysql

The form below is collecting the following information from users:
- Name
- Email Address
- Type of item being shared
- The number of items
- List of items being shared

The problem is that the email address and list of items being shared are not getting stored to the database.  All other fields are being stored properly.

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="feedback.php" class="pure-form">
 <fieldset class="pure-group">
  <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Sharetype" value="Nativity" id="SharingSharetype" name="SharingSharetype" readonly>
  <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Name" id="SharingName" name="SharingName">
  <input type="email" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Email" id="SharingEmail name="SharingEmail">
 </fieldset><br>
 <fieldset class="pure-group">
  <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Number of Items" id="SharingNum" name="SharingNum">
  <textarea class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="List items you want to share" id="SharingShared_items name="SharingShared_Items"></textarea>
 </fieldset>
 <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```html
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
    $Name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['SharingName']);
    $Email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['SharingEmail']);
    $Sharetype = mysql_escape_string($_POST['SharingSharetype']);
    $Shared_Items = mysql_escape_string($_POST['SharingItems']);
    $Num = $_POST[SharingNum];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Name, Email, Sharetype, Shareditems, Num, ShareDate)VALUES('$Name', '$Email', '$Sharetype', '$Shared_Items', '$Num', Now())";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
mysql_close();
header( 'Location: http://www.googe.com/' );
exit;
}
else {
mysql_close();
header( 'Location: http://www.google.com/' );
exit;
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: At least you have a missing quote: `id="SharingEmail` misses a closing `"`

Comment: Duh!  That solved my email capture issue, but not the textarea capture.  That is still not storing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
id="SharingEmail name="SharingEmail"
```

with

```
id="SharingEmail" name="SharingEmail"
```

and

```
id="SharingShared_items name="SharingShared_Items"
```

with

```
id="SharingShared_items" name="SharingShared_Items"
```

Comment: Thanks Norbert and M0rtiis.  Your comments helped me find one other error.  The textarea field name did not match what I was using in the PHP.  Thanks for the catch on the missing quotes.